# php - query doesn't get all value

Tags: php, mysql

please check my following code i am having 6 records shows also in $count print but getting only 5 records in array..please check where i am doing mistake

```
session_start();
$friendlyurl=$_SESSION['favcolor']; 


include('adminv/dsn.php');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT autoid FROM propertydetails where  friendlyurl='$friendlyurl'")
or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 
$autoid=$info['autoid'];
echo "auto id ".$autoid."<br>";

include 'config.php';
$rows = array();
$conn = @new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die('unable to connect');
$query = "select count(*) from images where parentid=$autoid and description<>'Not Active'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
list($count) = $result->fetch_row();
$query = "select path, description from images where parentid=$autoid and  description<>'Not Active'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$checkimageexist = $count;
echo "check count ".$checkimageexist; // count shows there are 6 records
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    $rows[] = $row;
    print_r(array_values($rows)); // getting 5 record instead of 6
```

thanks for your help

Comment: it's because you've already called fetch_row() before your while loop, so that first row fetched won't be processed within your while loop.

Comment: first of all change the names of query which aur executing it is confusing or plz run both the queries first in sql yog and checked what is the result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have 5 records.
Try this code:

```
$conn = @new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die('unable to connect');
$query = "select count(*) as f_val from images where parentid=$autoid and description<>'Not Active'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$count = ($result->fetch_row())["f_val"];
```